# How to check my progress towards "Tag Badges"?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

There are these Tag badges as we all know. How can we track progress towards these tag badges?

[image]

For all other regular badges i can track the progress from my profile as seen below. is there a similar place to check progress towards tag badges?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tag badges are tracked separately from other badges. You'll find the tracker for this in your "Reputation" box, to the left of where the badge tracker is. The gear will be next to the "Next Privilege" tracker.

[image: Next Privilege]

Click the gear and select "Track a tag badge instead" and you'll get:

[image: Tag Badge]

The tracker will automatically select the tag badge you're closest too, but you can click the gear next to the tag badge to select which tag badge you'd like to track.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Nice circle btw.

Comment: I just happened to be a hair faster on the _draw._ (The circle was totally an after-thought, too. And ignore the horrible pun, too much caffeine today.)

Comment: Excellent! found it thanks! this one is hidden deep. there should be an easier access for this one.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic It could certainly be more obvious. I wouldn't say "easier access" since it's literally a click away, but I would definitely say it's a bit of a non-obvious option.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic for users with all the privileges (currently >25k), it shows only tag tracking (since they don't have any more privileges to unlock)

Comment: Also worth noting that on child Meta sites, you'll _always_ be set to tag badges- There are no privileges to earn, after all. (Meta.SE still has privs, so that is like any other Main site in this regard.)

Comment: @ryanyuyu cool... I'll let me kid login through my account when he grows up. I must have it by then :D

Comment: How often is this recalculated?

Comment: @ilse2005 I'm not actually sure off the top of my head. My experience has been it usually updates within a few minutes, but sometimes the job that updates it fails so it sticks for a while. I'll see if I can find a reference that answers that question.

Comment: @Kendra What does non-community wiki answers means??

Comment: @VivekMishra It means an answer that has not been marked community wiki. You mark an answer as community wiki by ticking the checkbox under an answer as you write it that reads "community wiki". A community wiki answer can be edited directly by anyone with 100 rep, and gives no reputation to the answer author. It's meant to be a collaborative answer that many people edit and help improve.