# Do the colors of the progress bars on the profile page mean anything?

Tags: support, profile-page

I was curious if the color of the progress bars of the profile page means anything significant. The color of the Next Badge is yellow(?) and the color of the Next Privilege is green.

Are the colors meaningless or does the color have a meaning? I do not see a color legend or any hover tips, so I don't know how to interpret the colors.

[image: Next Badge progress bar]

[image: Next Privilege progress bar]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, the color matches the thing you're tracking.  So tracking a gold badge gives you gold fill bar.  Likewise, silver and bronze badge tracking are filled with their respective colors.  Privileges are green probably because of the association with gaining reputation.

Comment: And it looks to me like "tag badge" progress is always green.  Is that what you see?

Comment: Yes.  Tag badge tracking (instead of privilege tracking) is green.

Comment: A tag badge is both a gold AND a earns significant privilege; [the ability to close duplicates and re-open closed duplicates in that tag single-handedly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/206345), aka Mjölnir - Thor's hammer.

Comment: @Mogsdad a tag badge is not necessarily gold; you earn bronze and silver tag badges first

Comment: @TylerH Then perhaps the lack of specific colour is because a tag badge can be any colour? (Where do you see tag progress, anyway?)

Comment: @Mogsdad it's the alternate view from next privilege.  You can track next tag badge instead.  For example, check your meta profile.  Since there is no reputation on meta, it defaults to tag badge tracking on the leftmost panel.

Comment: @Mogsdad I dunno about tag badge *progress*, but the tag badges I've earned most recently show their color next to them: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh?tab=summary

Comment: @Mogsdad see also [How to check my progress towards tag badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315262/how-to-check-my-progress-towards-tag-badges)